# Diagonal number pattern logic

Tags: algorithm, logic

I want to device an algorithm to display the following pattern:

```
1  
9 2  
10 8 3  
14 11 7 4  
15 13 12 6 5
```

Is there a way to convert it into the following array and use the indices of the above matrix and find out the position of the number in the array:
1 9 2 10 8 3 ...

I can't find a pattern to calculate the element using the matrix co-ordinates, that is why I was trying to device the above method of somehow determining the position of the next number in the array.

Comment: Here's my C implementation, thanks to @MBo : [Git Link](https://gist.github.com/GitSpree23/e7884969abc86518f245e18246b848b8)

Comment: Glad to see hints implementation +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clues:

You need to know  formula for sum of arithmetic progression (here sum of natural numbers `1 + 2 + 3 +.. N`)

```
1st step: determine number of diagonal where k-th item of array stands. 
2nd step: get direction of this diagonal filling
3rd step: get number of place at this diagonal
4th step: find what number stands here
```